# Error in testing webservice from SOAP UI

Tags: rest, http-status-code-404, soapui

I am testing a REST API in Postman and SOAP UI. The REST API URL is like

> https://endpointURL.com/resource

When I am using the entire URL and submit a POST request, I am geting the responce as expected. But If I try the same using the SOAP UI, it is throwing a 404  error.
This is the SOAP UI Raw request.

```
POST https://endpointURL.com/resource HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 720
Host: endpointURL.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)
```

Error message from the SOAP UI

```
<html>
   <head>
      <meta content="HTML Tidy for Java (vers. 27 Sep 2004), see www.w3.org" name="generator"/>
      <title>404 Not Found</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1>Not Found</h1>
      <p>The requested URL /resource was not found on this server.</p>
      <hr/>
      <address>IBM_HTTP_Server at endpointURL.com Port 8443</address>
   </body>
</html>
```

SOAP UI Error LOG :

```
Wed Oct 26 17:36:23 IST 2016:DEBUG:Attempt 1 to execute request
Wed Oct 26 17:36:23 IST 2016:DEBUG:Sending request: POST /resource HTTP/1.1
Wed Oct 26 17:36:23 IST 2016:DEBUG:Receiving response: HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Wed Oct 26 17:36:23 IST 2016:DEBUG:Connection can be kept alive for 10000 MILLISECONDS
Wed Oct 26 17:36:23 IST 2016:INFO:Got response for [https://endpointURL.com/resource:Request 1] in 20ms (301 bytes)
Wed Oct 26 17:36:33 IST 2016:DEBUG:Connection closed
```

Can anyone please let me know,why it is happening. I have to test this in SOAP UI onl because,I have all the automation code written in SOAP UI tool.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How does the raw request appears in postman? Does it differ when it is compared with SoapUI's raw request?

Comment: @RaoNo both the Raw requests are the same. There is no difference.

Comment: 404 means you have the wrong URL - `/resource` in your case. Show the raw (working) request from Postman; you can get this by clicking on the "show code" in Postman.